# Creating a singleton service in Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, service, provider

How would I go about creating a singleton service provider in Ionic 3. I have tried several ways but I can't quite get it working. What would be the preferred method. In detail please.

Thank you very much

Dan

Comment: Which ways have you tried, please?

Comment: I tried making a static variable and static method to return an instance. Only problem is then I cant use dependency injection. I have read about putting it in the App class. I haven't tried it as I don't fully understand it yet